# Subscripts in my multiple regression model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, model

So, for my research paper I have to write an equation for my multiple regression model. My independent variable is STOCK PRICE; my independent variable is before/after (denoted TIME on my equation) which means it is a dummy variable with the values of 0 and 1; I also have two control variables of PROFIT and CAPITALIZATION.

So what I have usually seen when building a model is two subscripts i and j, where i is the time and j is the company. However the same company in my sample can appear more than once given that the before/after variable refers to specific events which can occur more than once in a company. Therefore, should I add a third subscript for the event?

My final formula would look like this

PRICE*ijk* = β1TIME*ijk* + β2PROFIT*ijk* + β3SIZE*ijk*

Would this be alright or is there some rule that regressions should only have the two subscripts i and j?

Or would it be better to define one subscript in terms of two parameters? i.e. subscript i refers to firm X impacted by event Y, while k refers to the time period?

Comment: From the design you refer, I think you should do an interaction term between time and company, which will then tell you if there is any variability within time across companies (I assume this may be a variable of interest for you).

Comment: "there some rule that regressions should only have the two subscripts i and j?" there are no rules for notation like this; simply write so as to be easily understood. If you think 3 or 4 or 10 indices is the clearest way to express your model, do that.